# search for string and return a specific column from file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file named test_wd, that contains

```
dkde456:test.test@test.be
dkde123:dummy.dummy@test.be  
dkde789:dummy_test.dummy_test@test.be
```

The first column is the user-id, the second column is the full email address. Suppose I am dkde123. I run a script, but the result has to be sent only to my email address.

I have written this:

```
LMUSER="`whoami`"
# So now I check whether my user-name is in the file:
if grep  "${LMUSER}" test_wd
then echo "found"
# ??????? How to create a file and send this file to my email address
else
    echo "not found"
    exit 0
fi
```

and now I want to select only column2  so that I can run a script to create a file and send this file to my email address. How can I do this if the *if condition statement* returned true in above code in place of question marks ?

Answer (score 3):

Lots of ways to do this. Here's a `grep`+`cut` variation...

```
# surround LMUSER with ^ and : to make sure we match whole usernames only
email=$(grep "^${LMUSER}:" test_wd | cut -d: -f2)

# $email will be empty unless there was a match
if [[ -n $email ]]; then
    # send the message to "$email"
fi
```

---

Or perhaps you fancy `sed`?

```
email=$(sed -n "s/^${LMUSER}:\(.*\)/\1/p" test_wd)
```

`-n` skips printing of all lines except those explicitly designated for printing such as with the substitution flag `p` here. It says "print this line if a substitution occurred".

To extract just the email address we surround that part with `\(`..`\)`. Then in the substitution we can pull out the text inside those parens with a [back-reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html): `\1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the email address with awk and so:

```
email=$(awk -F: -v usa=$(whoami) '$1 == usa { print $2 }' test_wd)
```

Set the field delimiter to `:` with -F and pass the username as variable `usa`. If the first `:` delimited piece of data is equal to the username, print the second piece, i.e the email address.

Comment: No worries, it was a pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

To send a message "Hello user" with subject "test" try (assuming `mutt` is installed and working):

```
awk -F: '$1==user {print "Helo "$1 | "mutt -s 'test' " $2}' user=$USER test_wd
```